# How to write a constructor for a template class using universal reference arguments in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a C++ template class MyClass with two type parameters:

```cpp
template <typename D, typename S>
struct MyClass {
private:
    D d_;
    S s_;
};
```

I want to add a constructor with D and S references as parameters, so it can
get D and S inferred:

```cpp
template <typename D, typename S>
struct MyClass {
    // can bind to lvalues
    constexpr MyClass(const D &d, const S &s): d_(d), s_(s) {}

    // can bind to rvalues
    constexpr MyClass(D &&d, S &&s): d_(std::move(d)), s_(std::move(s)) {}

private:
    D d_;
    S s_;
};
```

It works well. I can create objects from either lvalues or rvalues:

```cpp
auto c1 = MyClass(1, std::string("Hello"));    // rvalues

auto idx = 2;
auto msg = std::string("World");
auto c2 = MyClass(idx, msg);    // lvalues
```

But I'd like just one constructor using universal references rather than two
with each handles lvalues and rvalues. Probably like this:

```cpp
template <typename D, typename S>
struct MyClass {
    constexpr MyClass(D &&d, S &&s): d_(std::forward<D>(d)), s_(std::forward<S>(s)) {}
private:
    D d_;
    S s_;
};
```

It does not work for statement "auto w2 = MyClass(i, j);". The compiler complains

```
error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'MyClass'
auto c2 = MyClass(idx, msg);    // lvalues
          ^
note: candidate function [with D = int, S = std::__1::basic_string<char>] not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'int &&' for
      1st argument
    constexpr MyClass(D &&d, S &&s): d_(std::forward<D>(d)), s_(std::forward<S>(s)) {}
```

Command line: `c++ -std=c++17 test.cpp`, compiled with `Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.6)`

It seems the constructor can only accept rvalues. It's not the *universal references*. So my question is can I achieve the *universal reference* style constructor? (Also I want to keep MyClass as a template class with the two type parameters D and S.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this snippet, **d** and **s** are **NOT** universal references - they are **rvalue references** (because D and S are already known (deduced) within class by the **class instantiation**).

```
 template <typename D, typename S>
    struct MyClass {
        constexpr MyClass(D &&d, S &&s): d_(std::forward<D>(d)), s_(std::forward<S>(s)) {}
    private:
        D d_;
        S s_;
    };
```

According to [Scott Meyers:](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) the **type deduction needs to be involved** for variables of type `D&& and S&&` (**and in this form only!**) for those to be universal references,  so you need extra template parameters (so the types are deduced by the **class-method**(=ctor in this case) instantiation):

```
template <typename D, typename S>
    struct MyClass {
        template <typename DD, typename SS>
        constexpr MyClass(DD &&d, SS &&s): d_(std::forward<DD>(d)), s_(std::forward<SS>(s)) {}
    private:
        D d_;
        S s_;
    };
```

Enabling class tempate type deduction via constructor call can be done via class template deduction guide like:

```
template <typename DD, typename SS> MyClass(DD &&d, SS &&s) -> MyClass<DD, SS>
```

Comment: But in this case, the type parameter D and S won't get deducted (doesn't compile), right?

Comment: right, unless you provide your own [class template duction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

Comment: I'm not familiar with "duction guides" :) I should also note that taking the address of `main` is not C++ standard compliant, it's fine in C though ;)

Comment: @StPiere True. With this guide ``` template <typename DD, typename SS> MyClass(DD &&d, SS &&s) -> MyClass<DD, SS>;``` it works fine. Hope it could be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

if we want to initialize a product type just like what you define, we always use ***aggregate initialization***:

```cpp
MyClass<int, std::string>{ 1, "123"s }; // aggregate initialization won't generate deduction guide automatically until C++20.
```

and if in C++20 or the deduction guide is provided, we can omit the template arguments:

```cpp
MyClass{ 1, "123"s }; // after C++20, or by deduction guide.
```

sometimes, the requirements of *aggregate initialization* is not satisfied. in this case, ***passing a copy and then moving it*** is always cheap for us:

```cpp
template<typename... Types>
struct A{
    A(Types... args) :members({ std::move(args)... }){};
    std::tuple<Types...> members;
};
```

but if the moving is expensive as well, to be more efficient, we should use the ***universal reference***:

```cpp
template<typename... Types>
struct A{
    template<typename... Args>
    A(Args&&... args) :members({ std::forward<Args>(args)... }){};
    std::tuple<Types...> members;
};
```

However, we lost the type informations from the template arguments of class template, which means we can't use *aggregate initialization* for the members such as `MyClass<std::tuple<int, int>, int>{{1, 2}, 3}`.

fortunately, it's easy to solve this problem if it's not variadic template:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Y>
struct A{
    template<typename P = T, typename Q = Y>
    A(P&& p, Q&& q) :t(std::forward<P>(p)), y(std::forward<Q>(q)){};
    T t;
    Y y;
};
```

for variadic template, we have to implement it by TMP ways:

```cpp
template<typename... Types>
struct DataHelper{
    std::tuple<Types...> memebers;
    DataHelper() = default;
    ~DataHelper() = default;
};

template<typename, typename, typename...>
struct InterfaceHelper;
template<typename Data, typename... Refs>
struct InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs...>> : public virtual Data{
    InterfaceHelper() = default;
    InterfaceHelper(Refs&&... refs) noexcept(noexcept(Data{{std::forward<Refs>(refs)...}})) :Data{{std::forward<Refs>(refs)...}}{}
};
template<typename Data, typename... Refs, typename Head, typename... Tails>
struct InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs...>, Head, Tails...> : public InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs..., Head>, Tails...>, public InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs..., Head const&>, Tails...>{
    InterfaceHelper() = default;
    typedef InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs..., Head>, Tails...> base;
    using base::base;
    typedef InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs..., Head const&>, Tails...> base_cref;
    using base_cref::base_cref;
};
template<typename Data, typename... Refs, typename Head, typename... Tails>
struct InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs...>, Head&, Tails...> : public InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs..., Head&>, Tails...>{
    InterfaceHelper() = default;
    typedef InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs..., Head&>, Tails...> base;
    using base::base;
};
template<typename Data, typename... Refs, typename Head, typename... Tails>
struct InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs...>, Head&&, Tails...> : public InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs..., Head&&>, Tails...>{
    InterfaceHelper() = default;
    typedef InterfaceHelper<Data, std::tuple<Refs..., Head&&>, Tails...> base;
    using base::base;
};

template<typename... Types>
struct Test : private InterfaceHelper<DataHelper<Types...>, std::tuple<>, Types...>{
    ~Test() = default;
    typedef InterfaceHelper<DataHelper<Types...>, std::tuple<>, Types...> base;
    using base::base;
};
template<typename... Args>
Test(Args&&...)->Test<Args...>;

int main(){
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    Test a(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // works
    std::cout << sizeof(std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int>) << " vs. " << sizeof(a) << std::endl;
    // maybe 20 vs. 280, it costs huge!
}
```

sadly, it breaks the *zero-overhead principle*, because there is a huge space cost (***O(2^n)***) to store the pointer of virtual base class. it's just theoretical.

Comment: My case is not variadic. ```template<typename P = T, typename Q = Y> A(P&& p, Q&& q)``` seems simple enough. And clang++ 11.0 works fine with it. Sadly g++ 7.5 fails, saying ```couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’```.

Comment: @Long in what code? it seems that you try to use CTAD but there is not a deduction guide, `template<typename T, typename Y>A(T, Y) -> A<T, Y>;`, which won't be generated automatically.

Comment: I can't reproduce the compile error. [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/x4MxM5) works well.

Comment: You are right. I didn't write the deduction guide. And I retried building my code with clang++ it failed too (same as g++). I must have made some mistake yesterday :(