# why can't I pass an l-value to a template class constructor that uses universal references?

Tags: c++17

I have a templated class `MyClass<T>` that takes some iterable containing ints (e.g. `T = std::vector<int>`) in its constructor and does something with it.

I would like to be able to pass the iterable as either a temporary object (e.g. `MyClass(std::vector<int>{3,6,9})` or similar r-value argument) or from a named variable (resulting in an l-value as the constructor argument).

I would like to use C++17 template class inference (i.e. write `MyClass(...)`, not `MyClass<std::vector<int>>(...)`).

I thought that I could declare the constructor parameter as `MyClass(T && vec)` (a "universal reference") to take either an l-value or an r-value (just like I can with functions), but it gives an error. It seems like `T` is always inferred as `std::vector<int>` and never `std::vector<int>&` with classes, whereas functions infer `std::vector<int>&` when the argument is an l-value.

How exactly are the rules for template constructor inference and template function inference different? Can I avoid having to use a wrapper function (e.g. `myFunction(T&&vec) { return MyClass<T>(std::forward<T>(vec)); }`) just for the sake of template inference?

Run the code below on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6jox8v4xf):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
using BeginType = decltype(std::declval<T>().begin());

template <typename T>
struct MyClass {
    BeginType<T> begin;
    BeginType<T> end;
    MyClass(T && vec) {
        begin = std::forward<T>(vec).begin();
        end = std::forward<T>(vec).end();
    }
    int sum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) sum += *it;
        return sum;
    }
};

template <typename T>
MyClass<T> myFunction(T && vec) {
    return MyClass<T>(std::forward<T>(vec));
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> x{1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> y{2, 4, 6};

    // Warmup: Passing r-values works fine
    std::cout << MyClass(std::vector<int>{3, 6, 9}).sum() << std::endl;  // works fine: T is std::vector<int>
    std::cout << MyClass(std::move(y)).sum() << std::endl;  // works fine: T is std::vector<int>

    // Unexpected: Passing l-values doesn't work
    // std::cout << MyClass(x).sum() << std::endl;  // error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'std::vector<int>&&' to lvalue of type 'std::vector<int>'

    // Compare: Passing l-values to function works fine
    std::cout << myFunction(x).sum() << std::endl;  // works fine: T is std::vector<int>&
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a [user-defined deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides) after the class definition:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClass {
    // same as in question
};
template <typename TT> MyClass(TT && vec) -> MyClass<TT>;
```

See also [How to write a constructor for a template class using universal reference arguments in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64262171/1570972)